# Add Button to Title Bar only on one particular activity

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I am bulding an android app where I have three separate activities MainActivity, ActivityOne, ActivityTwo.
I have a title bar for all the activities. I am trying to add a Button to my ActivityOne Titile bar but if I add a button it is showing on all the other activities too. How do I make Button only on my ActivityOne title bar ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you user the 'include' variable in your xml ?

Comment: Got the solution. I made one more Menu_main.xml file under menu for my   ActivityOne and added a Button on title bar.